# Java string comparison fails

Tags: java, android, string, string-comparison

I've been looking for a mistake in my code for hours now but I simply can't find it. 
I could locate that the mistake is in this part of my code:

```
public String getType(File file)
{
    String type = null;

    try
    {
        type = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (type.startsWith("image"))
        {
            Log.d(logTag, file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){}

    return type;
}
```

This works absolutely fine but when I do the string comparison directly before the return statement I don't get all types which start with "image".

The same thing happens when I don't use the exception handling block.

I've also displayed the integer values of the string and they do equal.

In case it matters: This is an Android project.

**Edit:**
E.g I get

```
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20150906-WA0000.jpg
```

in both cases whereas I receive

```
/storage/emulated/0/Profilbilder/18186367897.jpg
```

only when I use the code above. And no Exception is thrown for this file.

**Edit:**
I created a new project and it works as expected now. Since my new code is not exactly the same but almost, I can't tell whether it was a logical mistake or the compiler

Comment: Did you try printing `e` in your catch block to see if it's sometimes throwing?

Comment: Please give some examples of the inputs that you expect to work but don't.

Comment: @Turix. Yes it does but only for files that don't have a proper extension. As I said this part works absolutely correct. But if I call startsWith outside the try block it doesn't give me all matches.

Comment: `type` must be null when `URLConnection` throws an exception.

Comment: @Samuel You can give us an example of the names of the files your are supplying.

Answer (score -1):

When file is null or URLConnection throws some exception, type must be null, then there is a nullpointerException on type.startsWith("image")

Comment: Yes, that is right but it isn't the problem. On this way I really do receive all types which start with "image"

Comment: NullPointerException won't happen if the exception is caught on the URLConnection

Comment: Indeed I only got NullPointerExceptions. But as I said this isn't part of my problem.